# How to convert a webform to a content type?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, webforms, importing-exporting

I have a long webform with about 90 textarea fields modeling a report item. Since the requirements of my Drupal site have changed, the report is now part of the content and should have workflow and other content type functionality.

So I want to convert my webform with its 90 fields to a CT. I know this will raise some problems regarding the performance, but I was thinking to overcome them by reusing some textarea fields (e.g. by putting them in different field collections in the same content type and changing their title and description only per field instance).

Is there an easy way to **convert my exported webform with its fields to a content type** with the same fields? Or should I do it manually?

Comment: @Mołot This is not what I want. That question describes a problem where a node needs to be created after a webform submission is performed. My requirement is an architectural change of my webform to a content type.

Comment: Oh. Well, in that case you have a problem as they are incompatible concepts with different origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to take a massive webform form and convert its *form fields* into a *Drupal Entity + Fields*. And yes when you want to re-architecture your website and do this for 50+ fields -- it sucks (been there).

Because some things like the Workbench module only work with things that are Nodes. And when you initially choose a webform to represent this data you've coded yourself into a corner.

This is kinda 1 place where Drupal is somewhat lacking -- interopability between similar tools (webform, entityform, entities, ECK, etc).

There are some tools to "move stuff around" such as:

- https://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy
- https://drupal.org/project/replicate

But they only work within 1 kind of architechure (Entities).

Comment: Yes, interoperability limitations here is a problem. I was thinking whereas I could somehow edit the node export of the webform to something that could be imported as a new content type. But maybe it is not possible.

Comment: @MariaIoannidou you can import data all right, via CSV file for example. But Webform authors did not decide to make their module compatible with content type on data-definition level. Webform is from 2004 **when there was no concept of fields or entities** in nodes at all. CCK was created in 2006 **when Webform approach was totally unsuitable to integrate into nodes**. And in 6 -> 7 transition, when CCK got integrated into core, Webform was simply too old to suddenly break data compatibility for all those who wanted to upgrade.